# SMTP does not send HTML message

Tags: php, html, smtp, fputs

Good morning,

I'm trying to send SMTP mail with HTML message. But not this gets the message.

So I did a test. Text messages sent successfully. Html message and sends it with little success.

And server problem that is not accepting my post html?

Server Response:

```
220 HOST ESMTP
250-HOST
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 40960000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH = PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
```

Response connection.:

```
 220 HOST ESMTP 
 250-HOST 
 250-PIPELINING 
 250-SIZE 40960000 
 250-ETRN 
 250-STARTTLS 
 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 
 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN 
 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
 250 8BITMIME 
 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful 
 250 2.1.0 Ok 
 250 2.1.5 Ok 
 354 End data with . 
 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3B74C7E40BA 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

My code:

```
private function conx(){
 $this->conxe = fsockopen($smtp_serve, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die('Erro log: smtp 12');
    return true;
 } 


 private function send_email($email_send, $sub, $body_m){
      $this->socket("EHLO ".$smtp_serve."");
      $this->socket("AUTH LOGIN");
      $this->socket(base64_encode($user));
      $this->socket(base64_encode($pass));
      $this->socket("MAIL FROM:" .$smtp_in);
      $this->socket("RCPT TO:" .$email_send);
      $this->socket("DATA");
      $this->socket($this->body($email_send, $sub, $body_m));
      $this->socket(".");
      $this->socket("QUIT");
      fclose($this->socket); 
    }
private function body($email_send, $sub, $body_m){
      $this->co  = "To: ".$email_send." <".$email_send."> \r\n";
      $this->co .= "From: $my_email <$my_email> \r\n";
      $this->co .= "Subject: ".$sub." \r\n";
      $this->co .= "$body_m \r\n";
      $this->co .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
      $this->co .= "Content-Type: text/html; \r\n";
      $this->co .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\" \r\n";
      return  $this->co;
}

private function socket(){
            return fputs($this->conxe, $string."\r\n"); //fwrite
}
```

I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually rather than just calling `mail()`?

Comment: because, authenticating the email. I work localhost. And then just step to the server.

Comment: You can set up PHP's mail() function to use SMTP authentication.

Comment: @ceejayoz: it would be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: But if it is giving error, with mail () will also give error.
Send simple message I get. but does not send HTML. Do not wound the target. And the server response is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/36108-send-emails-using-php-smtp-direct/). It's an alternatieve to the `mail()` function.